# My Xbox 360 won't start after receiving an update from Xbox Live

Tags: xbox-360, system-mods

I recently bought an Xbox 360 and got it flashed.  I connected my Xbox to a modem to get access to Xbox Live. I got a message saying that I needed to update my Xbox before connecting to Live. I started the update and just about halfway, the TV screen turned black as if the Xbox has powered off, but the controller was still connected to the Xbox showing that the Xbox was still on.

I switched the Xbox off thinking that the update was complete. I switched it on again but it didn't boot. I tried again and again but to no prevail. What did I do wrong? Was it because of the flash or was it because I turned my console off?

Comment: Voting to leave open as per [What's the official stance on hacked/modded consoles?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258/4797) and [How should we deal with direct questions on hardware modding?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3877/4797)

Answer (score 0):

One of the best things about knowing both hardware and software is that it allows you to be proeficient in embeded systems. What are embeded systems you ask?

They're pieces of hardware which were designed to run a very specific software, maximizing performance. That's why some consoles perform better than computers even when they have less RAM. They are optimized for games.

When you alter your xbox, you are changing it's hardware. Which is fine, if you know what you're doing. The thing is, you can't expect updates that mess with the hardware you messed with to function all the time. The update most likely changed its code, and what the hardware that someone added to your xbox did is now... obsolete.

In other words, you screwed up hard when you tried to install software to incompatible hardware.

Yes, there is a way to fix it, which is sending it to Microsoft, but they won't do anything because you altered the console in order to play games ***illegally***.

With that said, it's against this site's policy to assist in illegal actions. I'm sorry I can't help you any further. Cheers!

Comment: OP's question is on-topic as per [What's the official stance on hacked/modded consoles?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258/4797) and [How should we deal with direct questions on hardware modding?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3877/4797)

Comment: The solution can very well be due to having burned discs running once that triggered a failsafe, that's why I can't give that solution. Other than that, I pretty much answered it. THe problem is that he installed incompatible software for the hardware he has

Comment: This is dramatically unhelpful.  It does absolutely nothing to help the asker.

Comment: This answer might be worth a rewrite to be less technical and critical, but it answers the question

Comment: OP asks what they did wrong / why they are having the problem; not how to fix it

Comment: Everybody thanks for the help!but now my question is that if I get my chip or flash removed from my xbox,will then sending it to Microsoft fix my Xbox?sorry if my question is too irrelevant because I am a newbie    as I just bought my Xbox recently.

Comment: One more thing.I installed the update because it was like an'obstacle' in my way to get access to Xbox live. If I hadn't installed it,I wouldn't have gotten access to live.and now I want to know if there is something other than sending my Xbox 360 to Microsoft that can fix my Xbox?

Comment: @AbdulmalikArian To install the chip in the first place you had to break the warranty seal

Comment: Just make sure if you do have another question, you ask it as a seperate question